# Tool to remove records from mysql database table with generic where filter parameters

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra-activerecord

I have a database and the table contains more than 500k records.
I want to delete some of the users that are expired from the table. Some times I want to delete users based on other different conditions as well.

I have used Mysql for db, Ruby as programming language and Sinatra as its framework.

Is there any tool or gem that can perform delete operation on mysql table based on generic where clause?

Comment: You can do that via Mysql using `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=3;` , if you have direct access to mysql table.

Comment: In Users controller of sinatra framework you can use `delete '/:id' do
    find_record.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Record deleted"
    redirect to('/')
  end`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete the records from your application itself? Or using any external tool/client?

On Tool part - HeidiSQL can be good candidate for MySQL client. Assuming that you have connection & user permissions on your MySQL database you can delete the records using MySQL queries.